# Turn Monitor On/Off through remote desktop

Tags: c#, session, pinvoke, remote-desktop, sendmessage

I am writing a small utility to enable me to turn my monitor on/off. I am using the method described here (http://fci-h.blogspot.com/2007/03/turn-off-your-monitor-via-code-c.html) and I am writing my utility in c#.

So far I have managed to run the utility and turn on/off my monitor just fine when I am logged-in directly to my machine but the problem arises when I try to toggle the display while I am connected though remote desktop on my windows 7. The above mention code does not work either to turn the monitor Off or On.

I guess it has something to do with the remote desktop but I am not sure what it is and how to find a workaround for this.

Does anybody has any clue?

Comment: maybe something about the session that you are logged into.  Are you using HWND_BROADCAST?

Comment: Yes. I am using HWND_BROADCAST. I have also try impersonate as another user but also and the same user as the one that it logged in the current session but it did not work!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are being blocked by UIPI.  If you check the documentation for [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you'll see this caveat on the first parameter:

> Message sending is subject to UIPI. The thread of a process can send
>   messages only to message queues of threads in processes of lesser or
>   equal integrity level.

You might try using VNC instead of remote desktop. When RDP is connected to a windows computer, there is a new session created for the client. VNC will give you access to the desktop session that the VNC server is executing in.

Please note that I'm using the word session here to refer to a particular concept of the windows desktop, with it's own special rules. You can [read more about windows Sessions here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/07/24/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations.aspx).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I really need to use RDP. Is there a way to bypass UIPI without signing my application?

Comment: Hi I have just tried using a service to either send the message through the service but also have the service start another exe to send the message from there but the result is the same. Should have worked with a service? Does a service has higher integrity level?

Comment: maybe but it doesn't run in the console session.  There is a service option you can toggle in the control panel properties that's labelled "Allow service to interact with desktop" or something like that, have you tried enabling this?

Comment: Yes I did. Also the service runs as local system account. This should give the highest security possible yes? However every time I send the message though the service I am already connected through remote desktop. Does this affect the security level?

Comment: It seems that I can not send any messages through a service even when I am not running RDP. Can someone please confirm that it is possible to sendmessage to application from a service or not?